# Amicable Pairs (How many have been found so far?)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is simply, how many amicable pairs have been found so far using super computers?

I have been trying to find any kind of answer online that is up to date, but after searching in depth I can't find any academic papers (or google results for that matter) that date past 2009.

Have people given up on finding these numbers because they have minimal use in mathematics?

Comment: Other than the search done by Dave Moews in the early 90s I believe that most of the discovered pairs were found on PCs (I know that this is true for most of the pairs less than 10^14).  One can easily use the known algorithms to generate a few pairs per PC hour, if that amuses you.  I think that there is not much point to finding more general pairs, though looking for a relatively prime pair would be feasible and interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a list of known amicable pairs, perfect numbers, sociable numbers, etc. [here.](http://amicable.homepage.dk/tables.htm)  This is the most up-to-date  list of amicable numbers that I know of, although, unfortunately, it has not been updated since September 28, 2007.  It lists 11,994,387 amicable pairs.  According to the site, the list is exhaustive for $a<10^{14}$ ($a$ being the smaller member of an amicable pair), and there are $39,374$ such pairs.

**2015 update**: The link I gave above in 2012 no longer seems to work, but there is now another copy of this data (in a somewhat different format) [here.](http://djm.cc/aliquot-database/aliquot-database.uhtml)

Comment: Unfortunately that is the same list that I also found. I suppose it is possible that now that so many are found, the only thing left to do with amicable pairs is prove that there exist infinitely many.

Comment: Or else one can look for applications. There is a nice comment by someone long ago who reported having tested, one hopes successfully, the erotic effect of feeding $220$ to his lover while himself eating $284$.

Comment: It was al-Majriti, circa $1000$ CE.

Answer (score 1):

There  is a [database of amicable numbers](http://math.eku.edu/amicable-pairs) hosted by Eastern Kentucky University.

> The known amicable pairs are arranged in separate files according to the number of digits in the smallest member (3 digits - 999 digits and those with 1000 or more digits in one file).

Answer (score 0):

There are 1.2 billion amicable pairs known and listed at sech.me/ap/
The host of the website encourages anyone to join the search for new pairs
as volunteers in the BOINC project (much like the GIMPS project).
Volunteers are finding new pairs daily.